# How to convert latitude and longitude to XY coordinates on a map image .png

Tags: php, maps, latitude-longitude, geocode

So i have a set of latitude and longitude co-ordinates. I want to plot these points on a cropped map image. How do i convert these co-ordinates to XY points on the map. [image]

This is the image on which i want to plot the points
Few Sample points

Latitude  Longitude

19.8876 , 86.0945
19.8047 , 85.818
20.2631 , 85.7857

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Did you try some? And seems impossible currently, earth = round and nobody know the ratio & size of your _partly map of some countrys_. Easy convert is not possibly with your given data.

Comment: You better should use a given api like google maps for that.

Comment: I want to plot it on a map image ... by the way i know the size of the image ..can something be done then ?

Comment: Basilcy you need a formula that calcs your needs. In php it is like :`function getXYFromLatLng($lat,$lng);`, but the real math behind it depends on what you have and want to do. I thing the part of the world of your map is india, so try to get the most upper left point and most lower right point and find for that the real lat/lng or these.  Maybe you can map this. But the main problem is that round vs flat representation.

Comment: @SarthakMishra: you should find out the projection of your map, only after you have this information then you can get the pixel position. See here: [List of map projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections)

Comment: Most map projections have some challenging transformation. The easiest to work with is equidistant cylindrical. (That's not a typo!) The transformations are simple linear equations. Unfortunately, it is not a popular projection and its hard to tell whether or not your map is in that projection. If you map is of a very small area, then you might get good results with a linear transformation regardless of the projection.